# Disable few signature attributes/types in DocusignAPI

Tags: javascript, node.js, docusignapi, electronic-signature

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zU1OM.png

see this image here, You can see we have 13 types of signature (e.g. signature,initial,my name,my first name,etc...)

I dont want all these field in my app. so I want to disable/remove  while I'm using in iFrame. is there any way to do that, by manually check/unchecked the box or by API.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, but what you are showing is not really the result of Signature Adoption.

There are a couple issues I see from your image (Thank you!)

- That is a fax back document you are e-signing
- REST is a lossy API so when it is missing tags for a signer, it puts
  the signer in free form signing That pallet on the right is the
  e-signature secure fields/tabs you can place on a document to sign it, not attributes, so if you had placed secure fields/tabs via the api on the envelope you would not see those

Here is a link to our online DocuSign Help https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/RESTAPIGuide.htm